# Reload fragments in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have `ViewPager` with `fragments`. The adapter gets fragments from override method `getItem ()`.

```
@Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   return new MyFragment();
}
```

I need the `ViewPager` to reload all its `fragments` at a certain event (for example press the button). I.e. all fragments (even the one that is now open and its neighbors) have been updated. How can this be realized?

Answer (score 2):

In the adapter override `getItemPosition` like so:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and the `ViewPager` will remove all views and reload them.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `ViewPager` to set the adapter again like this,

```
yourViewPager.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

But the problem is it will jump to the first element location(ie. to your first `Fragment` in the `ViewPager`). To avoid that you can have a `Listener` that listens to the current item(current fragment) of the `ViewPager` and store the current position in a variable. Now you we can use this variable to set the current item of the `ViewPager` after refreshing. Something like this,

```
yourViewPager.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);
```

please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: When I'm trying to call .setAdapter(Adapter) I have an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:No view found for id 0x7f0903cb. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Anasteisha please try to set id for 'ViewPager' by calling yourViewPager.setId(R.id.view_pager);